# I had set up a contract on Remix ethereum IDE. Since it was not working I stupidly deleted it. Now how do I get it back?

Tags: remix, ide

I had set up a contract on Remix ethereum IDE.  Since it was not working I stupidly deleted it.  Now how do I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

If it is deleted, it is gone. Sorry.

Make sure to use github in future!  you will NEVER lose anything!